# could not unmarshal JSON from response body - Theme Kit received an HTML error page

Tags: json, webpack, shopify, unmarshalling, shopify-template

I am working on shopify e-commerce app where I use `yarn dev` command to push the changes to theme. `yarn dev` command under the hood executes `cross-env NODE_ENV=development yarn clean && yarn webpack && yarn deploy:live && yarn watch`.

However, all of sudden I am getting below error as an output of `yarn dev` because of which I am unable to deploy my changes and update theme:

```
Build completed in 0s
228 assets
1998 modules
49 WARNINGS in child compilations (Use 'stats.children: true' resp. '--stats-children' for more details)
webpack 5.52.0 compiled with 49 warnings in 89350 ms
$ theme deploy -d dist --allow-live
[development] 281|281 [============]  100 %
[development] 281 files, Updated: 7, No Change: 274, Errored: 5
[development] Errors encountered:
[development] (assets/account.js) could not unmarshal JSON from response body
This usually means Theme Kit received an HTML error page.
Http Response Status: 403
Request ID: 
ResponseBody: /tmp/themekit-response-565225865.txt
```

From the above error, I can see that out of 281 files there are *7* files **Updated**, *274* files with **No Change** and *5* files as **Errored**. So is there any way to track these 5 errored files?